# why use "isn't" in the sentence "if it isn't too much trouble, i'd love a cup of coffee?

Tags: grammar, language-formation

Why use "isn't" in the sentence "if it isn't too much trouble, i'd love a cup of coffee?why English users do not use "weren't" instead of "isn't"?

Comment: Are you thinking that the "If is [isn't]... I would..." requires the subjunctive?

Comment: It's a tense issue. *Weren't* is past tense and the conversation is about the present. If your question is about the subjunctive, it needs to be rephrased.

Comment: That was the first thought I had about why the question came up. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We do use "weren't", when it is in the past:

> He asked me yesterday if I'd like a cup of coffee, and I replied that I would if it weren't too much trouble.

The difference is in the tense of the statement being made. If the response above was instead a direct quote, it would read like this:

> He asked me yesterday if I'd like a cup of coffee, and I replied "I would if it isn't too much trouble."

The first case is a description of a past event, and uses the past tense; the second is in the present and uses the present tense.

**Update**:
However, if your question is about the use of the subjunctive as suggested in comments, then the phrasing would resemble this:

> He asked me yesterday if I'd like a cup of coffee, and I replied "I would, if it weren't that my diet forbids caffeine."

Admittedly that last sentence is a bit contrived, but hopefully illustrates the difference.

Comment: Isn't this a question about using the subjunctive?  "I would ... if it weren't for ..."?

Comment: @Chap: I don't believe so. Should we ask OP for clarification? It still seems to me that the tense of the description is controlling the tense of the wording.

Comment: yes, I think it may be the "if" that's relevant here.

Comment: @Chap: I am not following your reasoning. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems to me that some subjunctive verbs look like past tense. Trying to think of example... well, "if it weren't for my exam tomorrow morning, I'd go out tonight."  I hope the OP will explain, but my guess is that the question arises from the "If" and "I'd".

Comment: Actually it is the subjunctive that makes me confused a lot, for there is "if" and "I'd"in the given sentence. Since English is my second language, I really need you guys' help. Thank you very meuch!

Comment: I don't think your *weren't* is correct.  It ought to be: *He asked me yesterday if I'd like a cup of coffee, and I replied that I would if it **wasn't** too much trouble.*

Comment: @Jim: Interesting; in my mind's ear, both sound completely acceptable now that you bring it up. Theoretically I understand your point, but I honestly think I might use either indiscriminately.

Comment: Interesting;  Using *weren't* sounds definitely wrong to my ear.  Probably because when you conjugate it's: I was, you were, he/it was, we were, they were.

Comment: Just in case my mind's ear has been *led* by OP's question, I will come back tomorrow and see if it has a different opinion.

Comment: @Diansonn: I think that the most "correct" thing to say, grammatically speaking, is "if it wouldn't be too much trouble, I'd like a cup of coffee." And colloquially, many (most?) people don't observe the formal need for the conditional mood required by "if", and just use "isn't". But why exactly it should be "wouldn't be" and not "weren't", which also is used in some subjunctive situations, I have no idea! Great question.

Comment: @Diansson: One other observation - it *is* correct to say "if it weren't too *[or* so *]* much trouble, I'd drive across town and get a cup of coffee from Starbucks."  So there's something about being "contrary to fact" that affects the verb form, too!

Comment: Five years later, I agree with Jim: there is no counterfactuality in the first example, no irreal aspect. It’s just plain past, and _wasn’t_ is the form to use. In the diet sentence, of course, _weren’t_ is warranted because there **is** counterfactuality and an irreal aspect.